# Determine name of R package my code is in?

Tags: r, package

I'm working on an R package and (in the package's code) need to determine the version number when a certain function is called.

`packageVersion("mypackage")` works, but I'd rather not hard code the name of the package. How can I ask "what's the name of the package I'm in"? (Or directly get the version number of the package I'm in.)

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? Do you need the version number when the function is called or during building/checking? If the former, I would be curious why you need that.

Comment: Edited, thanks. When the function is called. (This is a client for an API, and I want to keep track of which version of the client people are using.)

Comment: See [this recent post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-December/434444.html) to the R-help mailing list -- `packageName()`

Comment: Perfect! (You don't want to add that as an answer, @Martin? If you don't, I think should...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This mailing list thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-December/434444.html) describes `packageName()`.

(As Martin pointed out in comments.)

Answer (score 3):

I have not handled working with packages. But I am assuming you can use something like

```
packageVersion(getPackageName())
```

While you can supply parameters to getPackageName to search for the package name you are looking for, I think just supplying it without any parameters will get the current environment, (and in your case) the current package.

Source:
The R Reference Index, available at https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html

Answer (score 0):

While in my case (custom R package managed as .Rproj),

- `packageName()` returned `NULL`, invisibly, and
- `getPackageName()` returned `".GlobalEnv"`,

the following worked:

```r
pkgload::pkg_name()
```

When developing your own package, bear in mind that {pkgload} itself comes with a handful of dependencies. Also, credit where credit is due – this answer was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73360939).