# Dynamically determine name of current package

Tags: r, package, devtools

I am developing an `R` package and in one of my functions I want to access files which are in the `inst/` folder (in the source code). When this package is eventually installed, folders in `inst/` are moved to the base directory of the package.

Thus, if I want to access the file `inst/foo/bar.css` I would use

```r
myfun <- function() {
   ## ...
   system.file("foo", "bar.css", package = "mypackagename")
   ## ...
}
```

This requires, however, hardcoding the name of the package. If, for whatever reason, the name of the package changes later, I would need to change these values as well.

I could think of the following workaround:

```
myfun <- function() {
   ## ...
   system.file("foo", "bar.css", package = environmentName(parent.env(environment())))
   ## ...
}
```

but I am not sure whether this will work in all cases.

Hence, my question, what is the most reliable way to access a file in the same package?

Comment: Is a changing package name really a major concern? I mean, every function and variable name in your package could change in the future. It seems like it would be better just do include some unit tests to check that the package function is working properly. It usually assumed a package knows it's own name.

Comment: True (and I do unit testing). However, in this particular case I have a feeling that the name will change, if I decide to publis the package on CRAN at some point. `Recall` is an R function itself, which helps the developper to avoid hardcoding function names, so I was wondering whether there  is at least a funciton which tells a function its package name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `devtools` package is [very heavy on dependencies](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/).

Actually, `devtools` relies on the [`pkgload`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=pkgload) package to get the package name, so you could save yourself the overhead (especially useful in e.g. GiHub Actions) and just run:

```r
pkgload::pkg_name(".")
#> [1] "mypackage"

# or simply:
pkgload::pkg_name()
#> [1] "mypackage"
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but `devtools::as.package(".")$package` did the trick for me.